# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: item' xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

i have a page with a collection view that lists the students at a school. when i select a student i should get the data about this student. the thing is that when i select the student i get this exception:

```
**System.ArgumentNullException:** 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: item'
```

the problem is that it was working well. when i made some changes to other pages and added some new pages, the error emerged. moreover, i inserted a break point at the line where i select a student to check if the values are null, but the result was that they had values. and this confused me.

this is the code of my xaml.cs page:

```
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        List<registeredstdinfo> list_total_reg_std = new List<registeredstdinfo>();
        List<registeredstdinfo> list_filtered_reg_std = new List<registeredstdinfo>();
        bool filtered = false;
        string year_id = "";
        string pro = "";
        public Accounting()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            imgAdd.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.add_col.png");
            imgfilter.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.filter_ic.png");
            imgshare.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("ALNahrainAlphaApp.icons.share_icon.png");
           
            year_id = Preferences.Get("AcademicYearId","");
            if (Preferences.Get("permission", "")== "Nursery & kgs")
            {
                pro = "GetAllregstdsForKgs";
            }
            else
            {
                pro = "GetAllregstds";
            }
           
            loaddata();
            var AddTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            AddTap.Tapped += async (sender, e) =>
            {
                var stack = this.Navigation.NavigationStack;
                if (stack[stack.Count - 1].GetType() != typeof(RegisterNewStd))
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegisterNewStd());
                }
            };
            stckAddStd.GestureRecognizers.Add(AddTap);
            
            ICommand refreshCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
               if(refresh.IsRefreshing)
                {
                    loaddata();
                }
                    
                refresh.IsRefreshing = false;
            });
            refresh.Command = refreshCommand;

            var FilterTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            FilterTap.Tapped += FilterTap_Tapped;
            stckfilter.GestureRecognizers.Add(FilterTap);
            
            
        }
    async private void loaddata()
        {
            popupLoadingView.IsVisible = true;
            activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;

            urlClass urldata = new urlClass();
            string uri = urldata.url + "/"+pro+"/"+year_id;
            list_total_reg_std.Clear();
          
            try
            {

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
                {
                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    list_total_reg_std = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<registeredstdinfo>>(content);
                    popupLoadingView.IsVisible = false;
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                    registeredstdslist.ItemsSource = list_total_reg_std;
                    foreach (var registered in list_total_reg_std)
                    {
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(registered.ExpectedDateofPayment))
                        {
                            registered.ExpectedDateofPayment = "...";
                        }
                        if (registered.ExpectedDateofPayment == DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                            registered.status = 1;
                        else if(  DateTime.Today== DateTime.ParseExact(registered.ExpectedDateofPayment, "dd/MM/yyyy", null).AddDays(-5))
                            registered.status = 2;
                        else
                            registered.status = 0;

                      
                        if (registered.Dateofpayment == DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))
                            registered.payedtoday = true;
                      
                        else
                            registered.payedtoday = false;

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Operation Failed", "Response Failed!", "Cancel");
                }

            }
            catch (System.Net.WebException exp)
            {
                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", "Please Check Your Internet Connection!", "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    loaddata();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                bool ans = await DisplayAlert("Connection Failed", exp.Message, "Retry", "Cancel");
                if (ans == true)
                    loaddata();
            }
        }
 async private void registeredstdslist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            registeredstdinfo selecteditem= registeredstdslist.SelectedItem as registeredstdinfo;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new stdregisteredDetails(selecteditem.stdid,selecteditem.name,selecteditem.edlevel));
        }
}
```

this is were i select a student:

```
async private void registeredstdslist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            registeredstdinfo selecteditem= registeredstdslist.SelectedItem as registeredstdinfo;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new stdregisteredDetails(selecteditem.stdid,selecteditem.name,selecteditem.edlevel));
        }
```

this is the xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ALNahrainAlphaApp.Accounting"
             xmlns:images="clr-namespace:ALNahrainAlphaApp;assembly=ALNahrainAlphaApp">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems >

        <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary"
                     Text="logout"
                     Priority="2"
                Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked"
                    />

        <ToolbarItem Order="Secondary"
                     Text="View Total Income"
                     Priority="2"
                Clicked="ToolbarItem_Clicked_1"
                    />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                                        Value="#f4f0ec" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                    <SearchBar HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="search"  TextChanged="search_TextChanged"/>
                    <RefreshView x:Name="refresh" >
                        <CollectionView x:Name="registeredstdslist" SelectionChanged="registeredstdslist_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single" >
                            <CollectionView.Header>
                                <Grid Padding="2" ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>

                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label 
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="StdID"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                               />
                                    <Label 
                                Grid.Column="1" 
                                Text="Name"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                />
                                    <Label 
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Text="Expected Date"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                />
                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="3"
                                Text="Edlevel"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                />
                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="4"
                                Text="Grade"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                />
                                    <Label
                                Grid.Column="5"
                                Text="Status"
                                 TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                />

                                </Grid>

                            </CollectionView.Header>
                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate >
                                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="1" RowSpacing="0" Padding="9,0,0,0" >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.4*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>

                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding payedtoday}" Value="false" >
                                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Grid" Binding="{Binding payedtoday}" Value="true" >
                                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightYellow"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Grid.Triggers>
                                      
                                        <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Text="{Binding stdid}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        FontSize="13"
                                    />
                                        <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Text="{Binding name}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        FontSize="13"
                                    />
                                        <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    Text="{Binding ExpectedDateofPayment}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        FontSize="13"
                                       
                                    />
                                        <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                    Text="{Binding edlevel}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        FontSize="13"
                                    />
                                        <Label 
                                    Grid.Column="4"
                                    Text="{Binding grade}"
                                    TextColor="Black"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
                                        Padding="10"
                                        FontSize="13"
                                    />
                                        <Image
                                    
                                    Grid.Column="5"
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                    HeightRequest="20"
                                    WidthRequest="20"
                                   >
                                            <Image.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding status}" Value="0" >
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{OnPlatform Android=redtik.png,iOS=redtik.png}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding status}" Value="1" >
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{OnPlatform Android=greentik.png, iOS=greentik.png}"/>

                                                </DataTrigger>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding status}" Value="2" >
                                                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{OnPlatform Android=browntick.png, iOS=browntick.png}"/>

                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Image.Triggers>
                                        </Image>
                                      
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>
                    </RefreshView>
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#0d98ba">
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckAddStd">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,5" x:Name="imgAdd" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckfilter">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgfilter" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                        <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarStackLayoutStyle}" x:Name="stckshare">
                            <Image Margin="0,10,0,10" x:Name="imgshare" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNavigationBarImageStyle}" />
                            
                        </StackLayout>

                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <ContentView x:Name="popupLoadingView" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="10, 0" IsVisible="false"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="Transparent">

                        <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Margin="0,50,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Color="Black" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" ></ActivityIndicator>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
   
</ContentPage>
```

i can't figure out the reason. i removed the bin and obj folders, cleaned the solution then built it but still nothing, what should i do? thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: the part where i select a student and try to navigate to another page:```await Navigation.PushAsync(new stdregisteredDetails(selecteditem.stdid, selecteditem.name, selecteditem.edlevel));``` exactly this line is where the exception appears

Comment: though as i said, all the arguments inside the ```new stdregisteredDetails(...)``` have values as i saw when i added a breakpoint

Comment: if you are positive there are no nulls, then look at the constructor for `stdregisteredDetails` to see if it is actually happening there.  Are step through it in the debugger.  Or look at the stack trace.

Comment: i put a breakpoint at the constructor of ```stdregisteredDetails```, it is receiving the data, but the exception still exists and no navigation occurs

Comment: Did you step though all of the code?  Have you looked at the stack trace? (3rd time I’ve suggested that)

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know how to do that, i tried to look it up but didn't actually figure it out

Comment: the exception object has a StackTrace property

Comment: alternately, just step through the code until you hit the line that is actually causing it